# Getting height of binary tree with objects

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I was given most of this code by my professor. we were asked to code and test a recursive method for computing the height of a binary tree. Here is my height class

```
public int height(TreeNode root)
{
    if(root == null)
    {
        return 0; 
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + Math.max(height(root.lc),
        height(root.rc));
    }
}



public class MainBinaryTreeWithLNRTraversal 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg 
    {
        BinaryTreeWithLNRTraversal t = new BinaryTreeWithLNRTraversal();

        Listing l;
        Listing l1  = new Listing("Ann",    "1st Avenue",  "111 1111");
        Listing l2  = new Listing("Bill",     "2nd Avenue",  "222 2222" );
        Listing l3  = new Listing("Carol",  "3rd Avenue",  "333 3333");
        Listing l4  = new Listing("Mike",   "4th Avenue",  "444 4444");
        Listing l5  = new Listing("Pat",      "5th Avenue",  "555 5555");
        Listing l6  = new Listing("Sally",   "6th Avenue",  "666 6666");
        Listing l7  = new Listing("Ted",     "7th Avenue",  "777 7777");
        Listing l8  = new Listing("Vick",   "8th Avenue",  "888 8888");
        Listing l9  = new Listing("Will",   "9th Avenue",  "999 9999");
        Listing l10 = new Listing("Zack",  "11th Avenue", "101 0101");
        Listing l11 = new Listing("Zeek",  "12th Avenue", "121 2121");
        System.out.println("Tyler Hansen \n");
        // insert the nodes 
        t.insert(l9);
        t.insert(l7);
        t.insert(l10);
        t.insert(l2);
        t.insert(l8);
        t.insert(l1);
        t.insert(l4);
        t.insert(l3);
        t.insert(l6);
        t.insert(l5);
        //Output all the nodes in NLR left tree then right tree order 
        t.showAll();
        t.height();
    }
}
```

I do not know what to put into height parentheses. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated i could provide more of the code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `height()` with the root node of `t`.

Since you did not include a definition for `BinaryTreeWithLNRTraversal`, I presume it has something to do with this: https://github.com/DavidSchirduan/ClassProjects/blob/master/CSCI230-java2/Assignment4/BinarySearchTree.java

Since there is no public accessor to get the root node of the tree, your code will look like this:

```
System.out.println(height(t.root));
```

This will work if your class and `BinaryTreeWithLNRTraversal` are in the same package.  Otherwise, you will need to modify the code for `BinaryTreeWithLNRTraversal` and/or ask your professor to include a public accessor for getting the root node.